# Alert me a message if i enter the same word in one search bar twice using jQuery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

**This is HTMl file:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="medicineSearchBar" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
      </div>
      <ul class="list-group" id="result"></ul>
      <ul style="width:100%; max-height:300px; overflow-y: scroll;" id="li-psearch" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
        <li role="presentation" class="divider-search"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**This is javascript file :**

```
var from_json_file = ["Genouillère renforcée ($30)", "Genouillère Small ($20)", "Genouillères XXL ($20)", "Knee brace long type ($50)", "Nexcare First aid Cold pack ($25)", "Orthèse de stabilisation ($55)", "Orthopaedic back rest long ($125)", "Paire Semelle orthopodéque ($280)", "Prothèse pour immobilisation ($90)", "Sac de sable de 500g ($25)", "Slip orthopédique ($70)"];
const search_box = document.getElementById('medicineSearchBar');
search_box.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  if (from_json_file.includes(search_box.value)) {
    alert('same');
  }
})
```

Alert me a message if i enter the same word in one search bar twice using jQuery or javascript
if i enter or search the same name second time in search it should alert me a message
i search that name seconf time then alert me but not first time
i m using json file for it 
how can i alert a message

Comment: This is not possible

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal Everything is Possible

Comment: based on your question you want to alert if `Genouillère renforcée ($30)` is twice in the search bar

Comment: Or you expect the individual work like `Genouillère` twice in the search box?

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal    if i enter  Genouillère renforcée ($30) first time ..then it is seleted  and again if i enter  Genouillère renforcée ($30)  then it should show me alert message.....and i ahve many  diiferent name like Geneouliee

Answer (score 3):

You can store already searched words in some data structure and then ask if it is already stored on every submit. I have used `set` in the code below.

If you try submitting the same word twice, the alert will be shown.

```js
const inp = document.querySelector('input');
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const used = new Set();

btn.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (!used.has(inp.value)) {
    used.add(inp.value);
  } else {
    alert('this word has already been queried');
  }
});
```

```html
<input type=text />
<button>submit</button>
```

If you want to trigger the alert only for the words that were searched twice **and** are stored in your `from_json_file`, then you can add another `if else statement` to the code above to check that as well.

`Array.prototype.includes` will tell you if the value is in your array or not.

```js
const inp = document.querySelector('input');
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const used = new Set();
const from_json_file = ["Genouillère renforcée ($30)", "Genouillère Small ($20)", "Genouillères XXL ($20)", "Knee brace long type ($50)", "Nexcare First aid Cold pack ($25)", "Orthèse de stabilisation ($55)", "Orthopaedic back rest long ($125)", "Paire Semelle orthopodéque ($280)", "Prothèse pour immobilisation ($90)", "Sac de sable de 500g ($25)", "Slip orthopédique ($70)"];

btn.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (!used.has(inp.value)) {
    used.add(inp.value);
  } else if (from_json_file.includes(inp.value)) {
    alert('this word has already been queried');
  }
});
```

```html
<input type=text />
<button>submit</button>
```

And to modify it a little bit so that only the relevant words will be stored in the `set` (not storing anything that is not in your `from_json_file` array), you can change the callback in `eventListener` like this.

```
btn.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (from_json_file.includes(inp.value)) {
    if (!used.has(inp.value)) {
      used.add(inp.value);
    } else {
      alert('this word has already been queried');
    }
  }
});
```

**UPDATE:** for `input` event instead of button `click` event

```js
const inp = document.querySelector('input');
const used = new Set();
const from_json_file = ["Genouillère renforcée ($30)", "Genouillère Small ($20)", "Genouillères XXL ($20)", "Knee brace long type ($50)", "Nexcare First aid Cold pack ($25)", "Orthèse de stabilisation ($55)", "Orthopaedic back rest long ($125)", "Paire Semelle orthopodéque ($280)", "Prothèse pour immobilisation ($90)", "Sac de sable de 500g ($25)", "Slip orthopédique ($70)"];

inp.addEventListener('input', event => {
  if (from_json_file.includes(inp.value)) {
    if (!used.has(inp.value)) {
      used.add(inp.value);
    } else {
      alert('this word has already been queried');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<input type=text />
```

Comment: but how can i search if data is in json format or array     var from_json_file = ["Genouillère renforcée ($30)", "Genouillère Small ($20)", "Genouillères XXL ($20)", "Knee brace long type ($50)", "Nexcare First aid Cold pack ($25)", "Orthèse de stabilisation ($55)", "Orthopaedic back rest long ($125)", "Paire Semelle orthopodéque ($280)", "Prothèse pour immobilisation ($90)", "Sac de sable de 500g ($25)", "Slip orthopédique ($70)"];

Comment: @NeetuYadav You want to check if any of the words above were searched twice?

Comment: yes  that only i m trying to do and i m not using any button

Comment: @NeetuYadav I have added that condition.

Comment: i m getting btn not defined in console

Comment: @NeetuYadav Because you are missing `<button>submit</button>` in your html, either add it or change the query pattern in `const btn = document.querySelector('button');` so that it targets the element that is responsible for submitting that form/input.

Comment: I m not using submit button and  i want to do it on click event in searcbox  or text box

Comment: It is working fine but i want to do it on click in text box .....only text box is there on form ...no submit button

Comment: @NeetuYadav Check now, it is working on key `input` instead of `click` event

Comment: you have written <input type=text /> but if i want to use <input id="hello" type="text"> i want to do it on  using id should be used in jquery code

Comment: @NeetuYadav Then keep your `<input id="hello" type="text">` and change `const inp = document.querySelector('input');` to `const inp = document.querySelector('#hello');`